# Factory CreateInstance argument method not necessary for a specific subtype

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture, factory-pattern

I have a factory class and CreateInstance method

```
CreateInstance(EntityModel.TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntita tipoParametroEntita, IParametroEntitaMultiValoreDataSourceProvider parametroEntitaMultiValoreDataSourceProvider)
```

The factory can instantiate two differents subtypes depending on the value of `tipoParametroEntita.TipoCampo.IdTipoCampo`

The point is the second argument of `CreateInstance` (`parametroEntitaMultiValoreDataSourceProvider`) is used only for creating instance of `TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntitaMultiValore`
whereas is not used in creating instance of `TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntitaSingoloValore`

```
public class TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntitaFactory : ITipoEntitaTipoParametroEntitaFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an instance of TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntitaSingoloValore or  TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntitaMultiValore 
    /// </summary>
    public TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntita CreateInstance(EntityModel.TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntita tipoParametroEntita, IParametroEntitaMultiValoreDataSourceProvider parametroEntitaMultiValoreDataSourceProvider)
    {
        if (tipoParametroEntita.TipoCampo.IdTipoCampo == (int)EntityModel.Enum.TipoCampo.CampoLibero ||
            tipoParametroEntita.TipoCampo.IdTipoCampo == (int)EntityModel.Enum.TipoCampo.CampoLiberoMultiLinea)
        {
            return new TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntitaSingoloValore(tipoParametroEntita);
        }

        if (tipoParametroEntita.TipoCampo.IdTipoCampo ==
            (int)EntityModel.Enum.TipoCampo.DropdownListQueryDataSource ||
            tipoParametroEntita.TipoCampo.IdTipoCampo ==
            (int)EntityModel.Enum.TipoCampo.DropdownListTableDataSource)
        {
            return new TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntitaMultiValore(tipoParametroEntita,
                parametroEntitaMultiValoreDataSourceProvider);
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

I'm doubtful about this adopted pattern as I always need to pass an instance of `IParametroEntitaMultiValoreDataSourceProvider` even when it is not necessary and moreover someone reading the signature of the method might be led to think that for creating any type of `TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntita` an instance of `IParametroEntitaMultiValoreDataSourceProvider` is required.

What would be a better approach? Two distinct factories? Only one factory and two CreateInstance (one returning `TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntitaSingoloValore` and the other `TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntitaMultiValore`)?

I both of the cases I should already know which factory or which CreateInstance to call so I should check `tipoParametroEntita.TipoCampo.IdTipoCampo` every time in advance. But I'd like to keep this logic only in one place.

Comment: You can implement CreateInstance with one argument and with simple logic(check ref. Impl, http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/FactoryMethod/ ) and leave a complex logic(in current iml.)  to the client which invokes CreateInstance().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a functional programming perspective, I use to look at the Visitor pattern when dealing with the so called "algebraic data types" i.e. different subtypes. Anyway I'm not always a fan of this approach, since it can be difficult at the beginning.

Therefore I'll give only the basic idea, so that you can quickly decide if you're interested. Also notice that the goal here is to write a code with function signatures such that errors can be spot at *compile* time, as opposite to *runtime*.

Now in a nutshell the classical way to achieve this, by leveraging a C# language type check feature, is to define a new visitor including all the different overrides of your `CreateInstance` with signatures:

```
public IEntitaTipoParametroEntita CreateInstance(SubType1 subType1) 
{ 
   // ...
}

public IEntitaTipoParametroEntita CreateInstance(SubType2 subType2) 
{
    // ...
}
```

where each subtype should have its own

```
IEntitaTipoParametroEntita accept(CreateVisitor visitor) 
{
    visitor.CreateInstance(this);
}
```

So that you can avoid `if` and `switch` and similar error prone subtype checking syntaxes and simply instantiate the specific visitor instead and just pass it to any subtype to be processed.

### DB tables

If there is significant commonality between subtypes, then splitting the subtypes out into separate physical tables is probably of little value.

Therefore, as far as DB design is concerned, "*table per hierarchy*" (which utilizes a type discriminator column to hold type information) seems to better fit your example: it enables polymorphism by denormalizing the SQL schema. To instruct Entity Framework to use this strategy, all that is required is to derive a class from the `DbContext` class, and add a `DBSet` property for the supertype, whilst not adding `DBSet` properties for subtypes.

### Reading links

- [*The Visitor Pattern - A Better Implementation*](https://oncodedesign.com/the-visitor-pattern-a-better-implementation/)
- [*Correcting the Visitor pattern*](http://logji.blogspot.it/2012/02/correcting-visitor-pattern.html)
- [*Inheritance Modelling Patterns with Entity Framework 6 Code First*](https://datatellblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/12/inheritance-modelling-patterns-with-entity-framework-6-code-first/)
- [*Supertype/Subtype deciding between category*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16543/supertype-subtype-deciding-between-category-complete-disjoint-or-incomplete-ove)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, you gave me the chance to take a look at the visitor pattern that I never considered in deep before. The point here  is that I don't have subtypes of EntityModel.TipoEntitaTipoParametroEntita meaning i ca't have subType1 and subType2.....